# how to convert html to pdf by DOM-PDF with proper HTML design

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

I am using DOM-PDF for converting HTML to PDF in LARAVEL 5.4
PDF conversion is good. But HTML page design is disturbing.

**showalumni.blade.php:**

```
<div class="panel-body panel-body-com-m">
<a href="{{ URL('pdf/'.$showalumni->id) }}">Download to pdf</a>
<hr>
  <label>Name : </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control1 control3" value="{{ $showalumni->name }}"  required readonly readonly>
  <label>Father's Name :  </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control1 control3" value="{{ $showalumni->f_name }}"  required readonly>
  <label>Gender :  </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control1 control3" value="{{ $showalumni->gender }}"  required readonly>
  <label>College :  </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control1 control3" name="colleges_name" value="{{ $showalumni->showcollege->colleges_name }}"  required readonly />
  <label>Course :  </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control1 control3" placeholder="Course name...." name="courses_name" value="{{ $showalumni->showcourse->coursename }}"  required readonly />
</div>
```

**route:**

```
Route::resource('registeredalumnies','Admin\RegisteredAlumniesController');
Route::get('pdf/{id}','Admin\RegisteredAlumniesController@download');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function show($id)
{

    $showalumni = User::where('id',$id)->with('showcollege','showcourse')->first();
    return view('Admin.showalumni',compact('showalumni'));
}

public function download($id)
{

    $showalumni = User::where('id',$id)->with('showcollege','showcourse')->first();
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('Admin.showalumni', compact('showalumni'));
    return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
}
```

**Converted PDF is:**
[This is the pdf file. But HTML design is not in proper way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uYCG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using inline css but the important thing to take care here is that you should not be extending the showalumni.blade.php with app or other blade file as in most cases when we extend the blade file from another file all the sections included in the master blade gets imported may cause hurdle.

Comment: I tried it without extend. Means all css and script icludes in showalumni.blade.php. But same problem.